# associating jobject with a value

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

```
jclass object = (*env)->FindClass(env,"java/lang/Integer") // C Code
```

Is there any way i can associate an *integer* value with `object` ? I want `object` to contain/point to an integer number.

Comment: Are you asking how to create an instance of `Integer` in JNI?

Comment: @Mat `object` is itself an Integer instance.I want object to point to a number.

Comment: No its not. It's an instance of the class, not an Integer object.

Comment: @Mat what do you mean by instance of `object` _(instance)_ ? I want to associate `object` with an integer which _(object)_ is the instance of `java.lang.Integer` class.

Comment: What you get back from FindClass is a **class**. (Hence the jclass type, not jobject.) You actually need to find and call a constructor to create an object that is an instance of that class. And this is **highly** googlable - "jni create instance of class" for instance (links right back to SO).

Comment: @Mat that was the reason i mentioned **C**. In C `jobject` is a typedef of `jclass`. You should also look @ [DOCS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html)

Comment: That's not the point. You still need to find and call a constructor to create an object. You'd have to do that too in Java (sans JNI) if you're handed a `Class` and need to instantiate it.

Comment: @Mat Then what does statement from the documentation `Returns a class object from a fully-qualified name, or NULL if the class cannot be found.` mean ?

Comment: A **class** object. An instance of `java.lang.Class`, not an instance of `java.lang.Integer` in your example.

Comment: @Mat if it returns the **java.lang.Class** object,why do we need to pass a string like `java.lang.Integer` in the arguments ?

Comment: @Mat It actually returns `java.lang.Integer` object not of `java.lang.Class` !

Comment: @SuhailGupta: it returns the same "thing" that `Integer.getClass()` returns. That is an object of type `java.lang.Class` that represents the `Integer` class. It does not return an object of type `Integer`. `Integer i = ...;`, `(i.getClass() instanceOf Integer)` is **false**.

Comment: @program-o-steve: no it does not.

Comment: @Mat How can i obtain the instance of `java.lang.Integer` class ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you read an understand [Confusing jclass with jobject](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/pitfalls.html#29158) in the *Pitfalls* section of the JNI guide.

`FindClass(env, "Foo")` returns (a handle to) an object of type `java.lang.Class`. It is conceptually equivalent to the [`Class.forName(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) static method: it does not return an instance of the class you give it as a parameter (`Foo`). It returns an object of type `Class` which represents that class.

What you can do with a `jclass` (or a `Class`) is find the constructor you want , and invoke that constructor to create an object of type `Foo`.

The JNI guide has an example of how you do this in the [Invoking constructors](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/fldmeth.html#26254) for class `String`. Doing it for class `Integer` is similar, except for the method signature.

You'd do something like:

```
jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer");
jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "<init>", "(I)V");
jobject mint = (*env)->NewObject(env, clazz, mid, 42); // your desired value here
```

(Requires error checking.)

Comment: One think that still haunts me is : _though `clazz` is an instance of `java.lang.Class`,how does `GetMethodID` return me the id of one of the constructor of `java.lang.Integer` class ?_

Comment: If you have an instance of type `java.lang.String` that you constructed with `String s = new String("hello")`, are you surprised that `s.toString()` returns "hello"? It's the same thing with Class. That `clazz` is one specific instance of `Class` that represents `Integer` (// with my specific instance of String that represents "hello").

Comment: I understand know. But [I did this](http://i49.tinypic.com/2gx4uhg.jpg) and [got a fatal error](http://i45.tinypic.com/28sq4xw.jpg). Did i make a mistake ?

Comment: `GetMethodId` takes a jclass, not a jobject. And you're supposed to do error checking, you can't know what you're doing wrong if you don't check return values.

Comment: So? What method is failing. The error checking is **not optional** if you want to debug your code.