# Creating a jobject in C doesn't work

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I want to transfer an `jobjectArray` from C to Java using JNI.
Currently, I get the following error:

```
SharedTable.c: In function ‘JAVA_model_JNIResultSet_getSpieler’:
SharedTable.c:116:5: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘(*env)->SetObjectArrayElement’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
ret, i, ptr);
```

I know that I should return a jObject but I don't know how to create it.
My struct looks like that:

```
typedef struct _Spieler {
    char vorname[50];
    char nachname[50];
    int trikotnummer;
    struct _Spieler *next;
} Spieler;
```

and my code looks like that:

```
Spieler *ptr = head;
jobjectArray ret;
int i;
jclass class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "model/Spieler");

ret= (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, count, class, NULL);

for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, ret, i, ptr);
    ptr = ptr->next;
}

return ret;
```

Comment: A complete example would help.

Comment: You can't assign c struct to array element. You should create Java object by JNI

Comment: Currently, my linked list looks like this {"a", "b", 1}, {"x", "y", 2}, .... How can I create a java object by jni of that?

Comment: What is the function prototype for `SetObjectArrayElement`?

Comment: SetObjectArrayElement
void SetObjectArrayElement(JNIEnv *env, jobjectArray array,
jsize index, jobject value);

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10650738/3386109) will help.

Answer (score 1):

As **@talex** correctly commented, you cannot fill a Java array with C structures. You should probably declare a Java class that is equivalent to the Spieler structure, and in your loop create each element of the array using a constructor of this Java class.

Something like,

```
public class Spieler {
    private String vorname;
    private String nachname;
    private int trikotnummer;
    public Spieler(String vorname, String nachname, int trikotnummer) {
        this.vorname = vorname;
        this.nachname = nachname;
        this.trikotnummer = trikotnummer;
    }
};
```

Instead of using constructor, JNI allows you get field IDs of the fields of the Java class, and set them separately (even if they are private).

Comment: I did it like you suggested but now I get an unsatisfied link error. Do you know why? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954941/unsatisfied-link-error-using-jni take a look please